# Tyk Notifications for OAuth2 flow (Synchronous or Asynchronous)

Tags: tyk

I am using Tyk for Java EE Application.

In my confioguration, I am implementing an OAuth2 flow, that will notify my system to save some informations on database about the access token generated by Tyk.

> ```
> "notifications": {
>   "shared_secret": "<%= @tyk_shared_secret %>",
>   "oauth_on_keychange_url": "<%= @oauth2_on_keychange_url %>"
> },
> ```

**I am asking if this Post notification is synchronous or asynchronous? If it is asynchronous, the is a configuration to change to make it synchronous ?**

In Tyk documentation (https://tyk.io/docs/tyk-rest-api/api-definition-object-details), there is :

> notifications: When Tyk implements an OAuth2 flow, because it will
>   handle access requests on your behalf once authorisation codes have
>   been issued, it will need to notify your system that these have
>   occurred.  It will POST key data to the URL set in these options to
>   ensure that your system is synchronised with Tyk.
>
> notifications.shared_secret: Posted data to your service will use this
>   shared secret as an authorisation header. This is to ensure that
>   messages being received are from Tyk and not from another system.
>
> notifications.oauth_on_keychange_url: The URL that will be sent the
>   updated information - the URL will be polled up to 3 times if there is
>   a communications failure. On a 200 OK response it stops.

Answer (score 1):

This is triggered after Tyk handles the access request and a goroutine is used to send the notification, for reference check [this](https://github.com/TykTechnologies/tyk/blob/master/oauth_manager.go#L214).